# Error while executing the selenium program

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

```
package Com.Automation;


import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Second_Findelements {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

                driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("gmail");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[(text()='Gmail - Google']")).click();
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException:
 The given selector //a[(text()='Gmail - Google'] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:

 InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //a[(text()='Gmail - Google'] because of the following error:

SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.
    Command duration or timeout: 30 milliseconds
    For documentation on this error, please visit: 

http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
    Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:55:52'
    System info: host: 'shaheena-PC', ip: '100.68.111.156', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
    Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=43.0, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
    Session ID: 62a7b699-fabb-4742-82dc-6f7785f33275
    *** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//a[(text()='Gmail - Google']}
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:647)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:353)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:490)
        at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:345)
        at Com.Automation.Second_Findelements.main(Second_Findelements.java:23)
    Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector //a[(text()='Gmail - Google'] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
    InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //a[(text()='Gmail - Google'] because of the following error:
    SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.
    For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
    Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:55:52'
    System info: host: 'shaheena-PC', ip: '100.68.111.156', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
    Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.annotateInvalidSelectorError_(file:///C:/Users/shaheena/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous3401694128124177427webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10633)
        at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_(file:///C:/Users/shaheena/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous3401694128124177427webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10664)
        at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement(file:///C:/Users/shaheena/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous3401694128124177427webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10668)
        at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///C:/Users/shaheena/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous3401694128124177427webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12534)
        at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_(file:///C:/Users/shaheena/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous3401694128124177427webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12539)
        at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<(file:///C:/Users/shaheena/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous3401694128124177427webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12481)
```

Comment: So what is your question? You did a code and error dump and then walked away. That's not how SO works. Did you read the error? What did it say? Did you google the error? What did you find? What did you try to resolve it?

Comment: actually my problem is instead of id i'm trying to use text() , contains() but its not working

Comment: i'm trying to pass email eg : driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Enter your email']")).sendKeys("shaheenashaik03@gmail.com"); but it showing error

Comment: You answered one of my six questions. You need to spend some time reading and researching the error. There is plenty of info out on the web already for stuff like this. Go find it and come back with a more specific question, if you have one.

Comment: You have write wrong xpath. Right xpath = "//a[text()='Gmail - Google']" You wrote extra "("

Answer (score 1):

You have write wrong xpath :

```
//a[(text()='Gmail - Google']
```

True xpath is :

```
//a[text()='Gmail - Google']
```

You have add extra "("

If you want to use contains

```
//a[contains(text(),'Gmail')]
```

Use unique text instead of Gmail in above xpath